# How to hide the console when using app.system(...) in ExtendScript ? (Photoshop)

Tags: javascript, system-calls, photoshop, extendscript

Everything is in the question. I just want to execute another process from a Photoshop Script (coded in ExtendScript) without the console appearing, or at least finding a way to put back in the front the Photoshop application.

Thx for your help !

```
function Main() 
{
    if (app.documents.length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var tmpFolder = $.getenv("TEMP");
    var exeFile = "convertor.exe";

    /** Save a temporary copy of the current document. **/

    var tmpPng = new File(tmpFolder + "\\" + app.activeDocument.name + ".png");
    var saveOpts = new PNGSaveOptions;
    app.activeDocument.saveAs(tmpPng, saveOpts, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);


    /** Convert the file to a MP4 video. **/

    var tmpMp4 = new File(tmpFolder + "\\" + app.activeDocument.name + ".mp4");
    var conversionLog = new File(logFolder + "\\" + "conversion.log");

    var command = exeFile + " -inputPng=\"" + tmpPng.fsName + "\" -outputMp4=\"\" -logPath=\"" + conversionLog.fsName + "\"";
    app.system(command);
    tmpPng.remove();
}

Main();
```

Comment: `app.bringToFront();` should set Photoshop as the front application.